# Cannot find column in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Why is my program trying to find teamplayers.player_id(which does not exists) when trying to run this line: `<%= select_tag "test3", options_from_collection_for_select(Teamplayer.joins(:live_player), "teamid", "playerid") %>`

I want to join on the fields playerid(from teamplayers) and Nid(from Players). I tried creating a foriegn key but that did not work

**UPDATE**
Here is my teamplayers migrate file, there is no name a attribute, the related in name for the playerid that is stored in this table is in the players table.

```
class CreateTeamplayers < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
   create_table :teamplayers do |t|
     t.string :playerid
     t.string :teamid

     t.timestamps
   end
 end
end
```

Comment: can you share your DB architecture?

Comment: you want the fields of the tables or the models?

Answer (score 1):

The `options_from_collection_for_select` method signature is as follows:

```
options_from_collection_for_select(collection, value_method, text_method, selected = nil)
```

So you're passing in the collection `Teamplayer.joins(:live_player)`, the value method `teamid` and the text method `playerid`.

This means that when it's trying to build your select options, it will call `teamplayer.teamid` and `teamplayer.playerid` on each member of the collection to create each option.

Assuming your `Teamplayer` instances have a `name` attribute, just try the following to see how this works:

```
options_from_collection_for_select(Teamplayer.joins(:live_player), 'id', 'name')
```

Note that without the 4th argument, rails will not know which option should be selected in a form where you already have data selected. For example when re-rendering the form after failing to create/update a record due to validation errors.

Comment: it does not have a name attribute. the fields are id, teamid, playerid, if i create a migration model will that replace my table definitions?

Comment: You could add delegations of methods to associated objects and use those here. For example `delegate :team_name, to: :team`, then you could use `team_name` as the text_method?

Comment: How do i get 2 fields in the collection for the text_method?

Comment: You can't. If you want to merge two attributes then create a new method that returns the text you need.

Comment: do i create the new method in the model, rails or html?

Comment: In the model. Those methods are being called against each instance of the model you're returning in the collection