# How to get 2 fields to show in a select_tag with options from collection for select

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to get 2 fields to display in the following spot

```
<%= select_tag "test3", options_from_collection_for_select(Teamplayer.joins(:live_player).where(:teamid => @ids).all.collect{|p| "#{p.Plyr} #{p.Team}"}, "Nid", "p") %>
```

Here is my model that I am trying to use:

```
class Teamplayer < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :live_player
belongs_to :fteam
    delegate :Plyr, to: :live_player
delegate :Team, to: :live_player
delegate :Nid, to: :live_player
end
```

I am having no luck because here is the error that comes back:
undefined method `Nid' for "John Doe Maryland":String

Now I know that it is erroring on the text_method spot(Nid in the is case), but why, because Nid is a part of the players table and and i try to delegate it in the model. How do i fix this?

Comment: I've already answered this for you in your original question. Also, your method names should not have capital letters at the start of them. You should be delegating those methods to models which have the methods actually defined.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot find column in rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21473589/cannot-find-column-in-rails)

Comment: So instead of delegate :Plyr, to: :live_player, it should be :plyr, to: live_player. which also means in other words i would need to define that method in the live_player model?

Comment: Exactly. Otherwise you're delegating a method to another object which cannot respond to it.

Comment: ok so here is what i did. in the player model i put `def name_team 'Plyr Team` those are field names that i want. In the teamplayer model i have `delegate :name_team to: :live_player` and i get the error: undefined method `name_team' for #<LivePlayer:0x5ed7c90> what did i wrong?

Comment: I have no idea. Please post a new question and provide the code to the models in question and we'll take a look.

Comment: I just used a table instead, thanks for the answers though